# Google Compute Engine VM performance issue

Tags: performance

we have deployed our portal on Google Compute Engine's VM instance. This is a 2 CPU 13 GB Ram with Debian OS. The link to the deployed site is http://www.beawel.com/UGC (Cloud VM).

Our testing server is at http://www.qspearcloud.com/UGC . Which is a shared hosting on some other cloud server.

if we browse the sites, the performance of testing server is better than the performance on google cloud VM.

I do not know the reason why on Cloud VM the performance is low.

Comment: The portal is deployed on Compute Engine VM and we are using Cloud SQL as our Database.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is loading lots of content, the problem may arise from low I/O rate.  If you're using a small disk (I believe the smallest default, assuming you're not using a SSD, is 10GB), then you're severely limiting your IOPS and throughput since those are measured on a per-GB basis. See ["persistent disk performance" in the GCE disk docs](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/disks#pdperformance).  I'd advise trying a larger disk and seeing if your performance improves.

Also, if your VM instance is stationed in the incorrect zone, this could result in high latency. You're definitely going to experience higher latency if your VM is running on a far-away continent :)

Comment: The VM was placed in 'asia-east-1' and the CloudSQL was regioned at 'United States', due to long distance between the VM and CLoud SQL the performance was low. Thanks MattH :)

Comment: Glad I could help! If you feel like this fully answered your question, consider marking the answer as correct so others will be able to find this advice faster :)